# How to install windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation

I want to install windows XP on my computer but when I insert a windows CD into my PC according to the installation instructions I am told there is a error due to low disk space.

What would I do to fix this error?

Comment: I've attempted to fix up your question a bit. However, its still not in a state where someone can really answer your question - we have no idea what your hardware is, and whether you are somehow REALLY short of space or if there's another issue. You might want to look around and get some pointers on asking a better question and improve your question as best as you can. Right now, its just plain difficult to answer.

Comment: Are you putting the disc in, restarting the computer, allowing windows to boot up and formatting the drive or are you trying to install start the installation from inside your current OS, also some system specs would be helpful.

Comment: yeah but i want to ask that should i first format(clean) c:\drive then intall it?

Comment: @SufyanShaikh: Common sense dictates that you can go ahead and format if you don't have any useful data, else backup data first and then format.

Comment: thanx,but sorry my account was being used by other person and i have not asked this question!...sorry to all.

Comment: This question is so very 2001! Takes me right back!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you did not format your Hard Drive before attempting to install windows.

When you format the drive it clears all the data off it and puts in a state of unpartitioned, no file system, followed by being set to whatever file system is used/chosen by you or the OS, for windows that would be NTFS.